# wall.post python vk

Tags: python, вконтакте

Появилась задача выкладывать посты(просто с текстом) в сообщество Вконтакте, помогите как осуществить данную задачу через python

Решение:

> Ну в том то и дело, что этим же методом и делается пост в группе, просто через авторизацию юзера. Посмотрите на атрибуты которые передаются в этот метод, там есть атрибут owner_id, попробуйте в него передать айди группы, где находится ваш бот(но с авторизацией через ключ пользователя)

```
import requests
id = 1488
message = "hello world"
params = (
    ('v', '5.107'),
    ('access_token', "token"),
    ('owner_id', id), #если нужно выкладывать в паблик параметр должен быть отрицательным
    ('message', message),
    ('friends_only', 0),
    ('from_group', 1)
)
response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?', params=params)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Братишка я не поленился и сделал даже целое видео. Кому нужно вот пожалуйста смотрите код. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLpxXI0f4WQ

Answer (score 0):

У вк есть открытое АПИ https://vk.com/dev.php?method=methods

Я могу посоветовать эту готовую библиотеку с привязками к вк АПИ https://github.com/python273/vk_api

Comment: я понимаю что есть открытое апи, но в данном случае просто выложить пост в группу  не получится, для этого думаю нету библиотек.

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/648070

Answer (score 0):

Не пробовал данный способ. Но думаю это можно сделать с помощью этой же библиотеки, методом wall.post, но понадобится авторизация через юзера, а не группу, попробуйте. Как получить access_token юзера можно найти в гугле, информации куча.

Comment: я понимаю, но  мне нужен пост именно для группы, он осуществляется с помощью >Этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя, полученным в Standalone-приложении через Implicit Flow, или с использованием окна подтверждения. Требуются права доступа: wall.

Comment: Ну в том то и дело, что этим же методом и делается пост в группе, просто через авторизацию юзера. Посмотрите на атрибуты которые передаются в этот метод, там есть атрибут owner_id, попробуйте в него передать айди группы, где находится ваш бот(но с авторизацией через ключ пользователя)

Answer (score 0):

```py
access_token="твой токен"
session=vk_api.VkApi(token=access_token)
vk=session.get_api()


def post():
    vk.wall.post(
        owner_id=42,  # id пользователя / сообщества
        message="hello world"
    )


if __name__=="__main__":
    post()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Сделал, тут ничего сложного